# Key Vault virtual machine extension for Linux - how to delete previous PEM file

Tags: azure-keyvault

I have successfully installed the Key Vault virtual machine extension for Linux on Ubuntu 18.04 (Azure VM).
The certificate from KeyVault is imported in the default store */var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault* in PEM format.

How do I ensure that after importing a new version of the certificate, only the current one remains in the store and the old (invalid) is deleted?

This is the current state:
*adminmox2@VM2:/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault$ ls
michalcpqtestwekv1.TestAcme
michalcpqtestwekv1.TestAcme.9c312a9e003b4df8a3a7881b5b149a6c.1651038865.1658814864.PEM
michalcpqtestwekv1.TestAcme.e1d6acf454d6474dab68dfb455e1b048.1650965285.1658741284.PEM*

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> If the VM has certificates downloaded by previous version i.e; v1,
> deleting that v1  extension will NOT delete the downloaded
> certificates. After installing v2.0, one may  need to delete the
> certificate files or roll-over the certificate to get the PEM file
> with full-chain on the VM.

According to  [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53112) on cerificates azure Key Vault will not be able replace the old certificate as of now .So as a work around ,you can use custom script and periodically delete old certs.

**References:**

1. [Run Custom Script Extension on Linux VMs in Azure - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux)
2. [Azure Key Vault VM Extension for Linux - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/key-vault-linux#key-vault-vm-extension-version)